# How do i change the apachesolr index environment based on node values?

Tags: 7, search

I have two apachesolr environment setup in my drupal instance. I want to index some nodes to one environment and some to the other, say based on some node values.

I could see that it always indexes to default the environment. I could see the possibility of indexing in two environments, but it is irrespective of the nodes value.

How can i achieve it?

**UPDATE:**

To give more detail, I am trying to achieve [shards in apache solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) in Drupal

**UPDATE - 17 DEC 2012**

*Modules used:*

- [Apache solr Module](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) and not [search api](http://drupal.org/project/search_api)/[search api solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr)

***Reason on why i need node values***

- I have a large nodes of a particular entity type, This makes my index so large.

  - So Decided to go with shards with multiple indexes of the same node type.
- So based on the node size and its priority of the node or proximity of the nodes location or users location , I want to split up the index to separate cloud servers and index them.
- Proximity of the node also gives me power of separate out search indexes at a later stage.

Comment: Do you mean that you have two Solr indexes for nodes on one site and want place some nodes on first index and other nodes on second one?

Comment: @Eugene Fidelin Yes two environment is two index.

Comment: Why would you do this on the Drupal side and not on the Solr side? Doesn't Solr support shards on it's own? If it doesn't, a quick and dirty way to do this would be to use a system that treats all content types the same and organizes content based only on taxonomy - but does in fact have different content types. You could use node hooks with a simple custom module to change the type of content being created on the fly. Without that degree of latitude, it's a custom module that maps nids to indexes and hooks into or overrides existing indexing behavior

Comment: @DavidFells how come a node hooks redirect nodes to indexes?

Comment: You'd use a different set of field names for each content type (just namespace them) and then in the search api, index those sets of field under a server's index listing for each type of content. I assumed you'd use search api, not the solr module itself, since search api is better all around.

Comment: @DavidFells Thanks for the update, I have updated the Question with modules i am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if it is possible to shard Drupal nodes into different Solr indexes based on arbitrary field values, I do however know it is possible at a node type level.

From the [API documentation](http://drupalcode.org/project/apachesolr.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/apachesolr.api.php):

```
/**
 * This is invoked for each entity that is being inspected to be added to the
 * index. if any module returns TRUE, the entity is skipped for indexing.
 *
 * @param integer $entity_id
 * @param string $entity_type
 * @param integer $row
 *   A complete set of data from the indexing table.
 * @param string $env_id
 * @return boolean
 */
function hook_apachesolr_exclude($entity_id, $entity_type, $row, $env_id) {
  // Never index media entities to core_1.
  if ($entity_type == 'media' && $env_id == 'core_1') {
    return TRUE;
  }
  // Never index news entities to core_2.
  if ($entity_type == 'news' && $env_id == 'core_2') {
    return TRUE;
  }
  // Default to allow.
  return FALSE;
}
```

So all you would need to do is allow some node types to be indexed by one core, and allow some other node types to be indexed by another core.

Comment: Thank you.. I am aware of this hook.As said it can do in entity_type level

Comment: Actually no, your question is rather vague. If you want better answers you should clarify exactly what you are looking for in the $node in order to send it to the correct index. Is is a field value, or a property value, or some sort of join on another table? If splitting on $node->type is not good enough, you should say why in the question.

Comment: I have updated my question. Pls let me know if needs further info

Comment: Thanks for that, at least now you may find someone with the specific knowledge that you seek ;)

Comment: Thanks man I have accepted. Just a glitch in my mind that stopped from accepting yours is great.